# Connecting to Windows server from unix through script

Tags: scripting

I am trying to connect to a Windows server say 10.1.1.10. This servers has a folder named RAJ in which there are multiple .zip files. All these zip files contain a text file called XYZ.txt. Now i have to merge the content of these XYX.txt files from each of the .zip file and create a new text document with the merged file.

So how can i connect to the windows server through unix and extract only data from the XYZ.txt in each file?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very wide question involving several tools...
First, to connect a Windows Share, you will need `mount.cifs` command. It's available from `cifs-utils` package (the name of the package may vary depending on distro).

A simple example of its use:

```
mount.cifs //10.1.1.10/RAJ /mnt/windows -o rw,username=Swapnil
```

`man mount.cifs` to see all available options, depending on your needs.

Then, you could write a simple script to list all `zip` files, extract them, and concatenate them. A simple example:

```
# For each zip file in this share, do
for f in `find /mnt/windows -name "*.zip"` ; do
  # Make a temporary directory
  TMPDIR=`mktemp -d`
  # unzip in temporary directory
  unzip -d ${TMPDIR} ${f}
  # cat all the txt files into one
  cat ${TMPDIR}/*.txt >> /pth/to/result.txt
  # remove temp directory
  rm -Rf ${TMPDIR}
done
```